# Flexbox does not seem to work in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

For a website, I am using some flexboxes. Those boxes work perfectly in all browsers, except in IE. I'm going to give you a simplified version of what I'm doing below:

```
<div class="row-fluid vertical-align text">
            <div class="col-xs-16 col-md-8 leftText">
                Some textblock, which has a 10 lines
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-16 col-md-8 rightText">
                Some other textblock.

            </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Doesn't work in IE.. Works like a charm in chrome and ff and even Safari.. Anyone?

Comment: Which version of IE? What exactly does not work? How is it supposed to work?

Comment: I only tried in IE 11.

Comment: I would have typically expected to see -ms-flex:1 and -ms-flex-pack: center; being used somewhere on the CSS to vertically center content inside a -ms-flexbox

Comment: Thx! Will try thuis tomorrow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, for IE, I had to specify a height on the .vertical-align class (in pixels). Which wasn't needed in for the other browsers. There it was good enough to specify height in percents.

Comment: Note that you need to place `display: flex;` as the last rule. Not the first one, as in your example.